# Create a new div container around block of code with domparser

Tags: javascript, domparser

With a string of:

```
<h1>aa</h1><p>xx</p><p>yy</p><h1>aaa</h1><p>xxx</p><p>yyy</p>
```

I want to insert a div container before the header, with the content before the next header as the content within this new div

`<div id="aa"><h1>aa</h1><p>xx</p><p>yy</p></div><div id="aaa"><h1>aaa</h1><p>xxx</p><p>yyy</p></div>`

so far this is what I've made

```js
let s = "<h1>aa</h1><p>xx</p><p>yy</p><h1>aaa</h1><p>xxx</p><p>yyy</p>";

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(s, 'text/html');
const elems = doc.body.querySelectorAll('*');

[...elems].forEach(el => {
  if (el.textContent !== '' && el.matches('H1')) {
    // create div container
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    //Set Id 
    div.id = el.textContent;

    // Get the next sibling next until H1
    var siblings = nextUntil(el, 'H1');
    for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
      // move sibling into div
      div.appendChild(siblings[i]);
    }

    // insert div before el in the DOM tree
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(div, el.nextSibling);
  }
});

function nextUntil(elem, selector) {
  // Setup siblings array
  var siblings = [];
  // Get the next sibling element
  elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
  // As long as a sibling exists
  while (elem) {
    // If we've reached our match
    if (elem.matches(selector))
      break;

    // Otherwise, push it to the siblings array
    siblings.push(elem);

    // Get the next sibling element
    elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
  }
  return siblings;
}

console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Which creates a div nicely but after the header. How do I tweak it to create the header before the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepend current element to `div` container

```
//Prepend current element
div.insertBefore(el, div.firstChild);
```

```js
let s = "<h1>aa</h1><p>xx</p><p>yy</p><h1>aaa</h1><p>xxx</p><p>yyy</p>";

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(s, 'text/html');
const elems = doc.body.querySelectorAll('*');

[...elems].forEach(el => {
    if (el.textContent !== '' && el.matches('H1')) {
    // create div container
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    //Set Id 
    div.id = el.textContent;

    // Get the next sibling next until H1
    var siblings = nextUntil(el, 'H1');
    for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
        // move sibling into div
        div.appendChild(siblings[i]);
    }

    // insert div before el in the DOM tree
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(div, el.nextSibling);
    
    //Prepend current element
    div.insertBefore(el, div.firstChild);
  }
});

function nextUntil(elem, selector) {
    // Setup siblings array
    var siblings = [];
    // Get the next sibling element
    elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
    // As long as a sibling exists
    while (elem) {
        // If we've reached our match
        if (elem.matches(selector))
        break;

        // Otherwise, push it to the siblings array
        siblings.push(elem);

        // Get the next sibling element
        elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
    }
    return siblings;
}

console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

---

You can append current element then selected siblings

```
// Get the next sibling next until H1
var siblings = nextUntil(el, 'H1');

// insert div before el in the DOM tree
el.parentNode.insertBefore(div, el.nextSibling);

//Append the current element
div.appendChild(el);
// move sibling into div
for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
  div.appendChild(siblings[i]);
}
```

```js
let s = "<h1>aa</h1><p>xx</p><p>yy</p><h1>aaa</h1><p>xxx</p><p>yyy</p>";

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(s, 'text/html');
const elems = doc.body.querySelectorAll('*');

[...elems].forEach(el => {
  if (el.textContent !== '' && el.matches('H1')) {
    // create div container
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    //Set Id 
    div.id = el.textContent;

    // Get the next sibling next until H1
    var siblings = nextUntil(el, 'H1');

    // insert div before el in the DOM tree
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(div, el.nextSibling);
    div.appendChild(el);
    for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
      // move sibling into div
      div.appendChild(siblings[i]);
    }


  }
});

function nextUntil(elem, selector) {
  // Setup siblings array
  var siblings = [];
  // Get the next sibling element
  elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
  // As long as a sibling exists
  while (elem) {
    // If we've reached our match
    if (elem.matches(selector))
      break;

    // Otherwise, push it to the siblings array
    siblings.push(elem);

    // Get the next sibling element
    elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
  }
  return siblings;
}

console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```